Flutter upgrade error to latest version such as shared.sh
When i try to upgrade flutter to latest version, i get this error:
/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/home/develop/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 88: 48234 Abort trap: 6           ( mkdir -p "$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache"; local revision="$(cd "$FLUTTER_ROOT"; git rev-parse HEAD)"; local compilekey="$revision:$FLUTTER_TOOL_ARGS"; if [[ ! -f "$SNAPSHOT_PATH" || ! -s "$STAMP_PATH" || "$(cat "$STAMP_PATH")" != "$compilekey" || "$FLUTTER_TOOLS_DIR/pubspec.yaml" -nt "$FLUTTER_TOOLS_DIR/pubspec.lock" ]]; then
    _wait_for_lock; if [[ -f "$SNAPSHOT_PATH" && -s "$STAMP_PATH" && "$(cat "$STAMP_PATH")" == "$compilekey" && "$FLUTTER_TOOLS_DIR/pubspec.yaml" -ot "$FLUTTER_TOOLS_DIR/pubspec.lock" ]]; then
        exit $?;
    fi; rm -f "$FLUTTER_ROOT/version"; rm -f "$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache/flutter.version.json"; touch "$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache/.dartignore"; "$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.sh"; if [[ "$BIN_NAME" == 'dart' ]]; then
        return;
    fi; echo Building flutter tool... 1>&2; if [[ "$CI" == "true" || "$BOT" == "true" || "$CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION" == "true" || "$CHROME_HEADLESS" == "1" ]]; then
        PUB_ENVIRONMENT="$PUB_ENVIRONMENT:flutter_bot";
    else
        export PUB_SUMMARY_ONLY=1;
    fi; export PUB_ENVIRONMENT="$PUB_ENVIRONMENT:flutter_install"; pub_upgrade_with_retry; SNAPSHOT_PATH_OLD="$SNAPSHOT_PATH.old"; if [ -f "$SNAPSHOT_PATH" ]; then
        mv "$SNAPSHOT_PATH" "$SNAPSHOT_PATH_OLD";
    fi; "$DART" --verbosity=error --disable-dart-dev $FLUTTER_TOOL_ARGS --snapshot="$SNAPSHOT_PATH" --snapshot-kind="app-jit" --packages="$FLUTTER_TOOLS_DIR/.dart_tool/package_config.json" --no-enable-mirrors "$SCRIPT_PATH" > /dev/null; echo "$compilekey" > "$STAMP_PATH"; if [ -f "$SNAPSHOT_PATH_OLD" ]; then
        rm -f "$SNAPSHOT_PATH_OLD";
    fi;
fi; exit $? )

i had to download latest version of flutter when i get this error and i can't solve
flutter home:
$echo $FLUTTER_ROOT
/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/home/develop/flutter

